# Xorg page allocation failure and baloo engine errors on KDE

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, kde-plasma-5, baloo

So basically I leave my computer alone for quite a bit of time. I have the settings set to the displays turning off and I can wake the machine by pressing a key or moving the mouse. But today it seems like Xorg crashed - I couldn't wake the machine.

First, I'm using Arch Linux, all packages updated, no testing packages. My setup is just KDE + Xorg.

When I check my journal logs (`journalctl -xe`) I see about 300 occurences of (all with the same timestamp, which is kind of worrying):

```
Mar 13 20:03:04 Ethan-PC baloo_file_extractor[2164]: org.kde.baloo.engine: PostingDB::put MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
Mar 13 20:03:04 Ethan-PC baloo_file_extractor[2164]: org.kde.baloo.engine: PositionDB::put MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
```

Then I get this:

```
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: Xorg: page allocation failure: order:4, mode:0x40cc0(GFP_KERNEL|__GFP_COMP), nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: CPU: 7 PID: 1541 Comm: Xorg Tainted: P           OE     5.5.8-arch1-1 #1
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: Hardware name: To Be Filled By O.E.M. To Be Filled By O.E.M./X370 Killer SLI/ac, BIOS P5.40 07/03/2019
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: Call Trace:
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  dump_stack+0x66/0x90
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  warn_alloc.cold+0x78/0xdc
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? __alloc_pages_direct_compact+0x140/0x160
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  __alloc_pages_slowpath+0xd91/0xdd0
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x2cd/0x320
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? _nv000491kms+0x50/0x50 [nvidia_modeset]
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  kmalloc_order+0x1b/0x80
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  kmalloc_order_trace+0x1d/0xb0
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? _nv000491kms+0x50/0x50 [nvidia_modeset]
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  nvkms_alloc+0x20/0x50 [nvidia_modeset]
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  _nv002521kms+0x16/0x30 [nvidia_modeset]
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? _nv002628kms+0x68/0x1f70 [nvidia_modeset]
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? __switch_to_asm+0x34/0x70
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? sched_clock_cpu+0x10/0xd0
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x2cd/0x320
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? _nv000491kms+0x50/0x50 [nvidia_modeset]
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? _nv000620kms+0x31/0xe0 [nvidia_modeset]
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? _copy_from_user+0x37/0x60
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? _nv000491kms+0x50/0x50 [nvidia_modeset]
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? nvKmsIoctl+0x96/0x1d0 [nvidia_modeset]
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? _raw_spin_lock_irqsave+0x26/0x50
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? nvkms_ioctl_common+0x3b/0x80 [nvidia_modeset]
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? nvkms_ioctl+0xcd/0x100 [nvidia_modeset]
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? nvidia_frontend_unlocked_ioctl+0x37/0x50 [nvidia]
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? do_vfs_ioctl+0x4b7/0x730
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? syscall_trace_enter+0x19c/0x2e0
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? ksys_ioctl+0x5e/0x90
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? __x64_sys_ioctl+0x16/0x20
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? do_syscall_64+0x4e/0x150
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: Mem-Info:
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: active_anon:2663633 inactive_anon:317428 isolated_anon:0
                                  active_file:237527 inactive_file:429143 isolated_file:0
                                  unevictable:20 dirty:355 writeback:0 unstable:0
                                  slab_reclaimable:109697 slab_unreclaimable:130597
                                  mapped:209988 shmem:75128 pagetables:27568 bounce:0
                                  free:74251 free_pcp:6 free_cma:0
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: Node 0 active_anon:10654532kB inactive_anon:1269712kB active_file:950108kB inactive_file:1716572kB unevictable:80kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB mapped:839952kB dirty:1420kB writeback:0kB shmem:300512kB shmem_thp: 0kB shmem_pmdmapped: 0kB anon_thp: 0kB writeback_tmp:0kB unstable:0kB all_unreclaimable? no
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: Node 0 DMA free:15852kB min:64kB low:80kB high:96kB reserved_highatomic:0KB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB writepending:0kB present:15996kB managed:15868kB mlocked:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 3430 15899 15899 15899
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: Node 0 DMA32 free:115736kB min:14564kB low:18204kB high:21844kB reserved_highatomic:0KB active_anon:2203672kB inactive_anon:425100kB active_file:130252kB inactive_file:378824kB unevictable:0kB writepending:328kB present:3596512kB managed:3596244kB mlocked:0kB kernel_stack:2552kB pagetables:13076kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 12469 12469 12469
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: Node 0 Normal free:165416kB min:54996kB low:68232kB high:81468kB reserved_highatomic:2048KB active_anon:8450860kB inactive_anon:844612kB active_file:819856kB inactive_file:1337748kB unevictable:80kB writepending:1092kB present:13094400kB managed:12776884kB mlocked:80kB kernel_stack:26472kB pagetables:97196kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:24kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: Node 0 DMA: 3*4kB (U) 2*8kB (U) 1*16kB (U) 0*32kB 3*64kB (U) 0*128kB 1*256kB (U) 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 1*2048kB (M) 3*4096kB (M) = 15852kB
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: Node 0 DMA32: 9609*4kB (UME) 8200*8kB (UME) 755*16kB (UM) 1*32kB (U) 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 116148kB
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: Node 0 Normal: 24538*4kB (UMEH) 6088*8kB (UMEH) 1214*16kB (UMEH) 2*32kB (H) 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 166344kB
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: 740183 total pagecache pages
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: 5031 pages in swap cache
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: Swap cache stats: add 706080, delete 701049, find 30491/49074
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: Free swap  = 14315772kB
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: Total swap = 16777212kB
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: 4176727 pages RAM
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: 79478 pages reserved
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: 0 pages hwpoisoned
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: BUG: unable to handle page fault for address: 0000000000006f80
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: #PF: supervisor read access in kernel mode
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: #PF: error_code(0x0000) - not-present page
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: PGD 0 P4D 0 
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: Oops: 0000 [#1] PREEMPT SMP NOPTI
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: CPU: 7 PID: 1541 Comm: Xorg Tainted: P           OE     5.5.8-arch1-1 #1
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: Hardware name: To Be Filled By O.E.M. To Be Filled By O.E.M./X370 Killer SLI/ac, BIOS P5.40 07/03/2019
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: RIP: 0010:_nv002476kms+0x60/0x100 [nvidia_modeset]
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: Code: eb 40 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 48 c7 03 00 00 00 00 c6 43 08 00 41 8b 86 d8 00 00 00 83 c5 01 48 81 c3 d0 03 00 00 39 e8 76 18 <48> 8b 3b 48 85 ff 74 ea 80 7b 08 00 75 d2 e8 ed d2 ff ff eb cb 0f
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: RSP: 0018:ffff9a2980e6bba8 EFLAGS: 00010202
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: RAX: 0000000000000004 RBX: 0000000000006f80 RCX: 0000000000000004
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: RDX: 0000000000000060 RSI: 0000000000006f80 RDI: ffff8e335e887008
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: RBP: 0000000000000000 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: R10: 0000000000000004 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: 0000000000006f80
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: R13: 0000000000006f80 R14: ffff8e335e887008 R15: 0000000000000001
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: FS:  00007fe00882edc0(0000) GS:ffff8e338e9c0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: CR2: 0000000000006f80 CR3: 00000003f0b3c000 CR4: 00000000003406e0
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: Call Trace:
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? _nv002628kms+0x3aa/0x1f70 [nvidia_modeset]
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? sched_clock_cpu+0x10/0xd0
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x2cd/0x320
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? _nv000491kms+0x50/0x50 [nvidia_modeset]
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? _nv000620kms+0x31/0xe0 [nvidia_modeset]
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? _copy_from_user+0x37/0x60
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? _nv000491kms+0x50/0x50 [nvidia_modeset]
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? nvKmsIoctl+0x96/0x1d0 [nvidia_modeset]
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? _raw_spin_lock_irqsave+0x26/0x50
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? nvkms_ioctl_common+0x3b/0x80 [nvidia_modeset]
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? nvkms_ioctl+0xcd/0x100 [nvidia_modeset]
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? nvidia_frontend_unlocked_ioctl+0x37/0x50 [nvidia]
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? do_vfs_ioctl+0x4b7/0x730
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? syscall_trace_enter+0x19c/0x2e0
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? ksys_ioctl+0x5e/0x90
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? __x64_sys_ioctl+0x16/0x20
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? do_syscall_64+0x4e/0x150
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  ? entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: Modules linked in: rfcomm fuse ecryptfs encrypted_keys trusted tpm ccm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep vmnet(OE) nct6775 hwmon_vid snd_hda_codec_hdmi nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) iwlmvm snd_hda_codec_realtek uvcvideo edac_mce_amd mac80211 snd_hda_codec_generic kvm_amd wmi_bmof mxm_wmi ledtrig_audio videobuf2_vmalloc snd_usb_audio snd_hda_intel nvidia(POE) videobuf2_memops snd_intel_dspcfg libarc4 pktcdvd videobuf2_v4l2 kvm snd_usbmidi_lib     snd_hda_codec nls_iso8859_1 nls_cp437 btusb snd_hda_core snd_rawmidi vfat btrtl irqbypass iwlwifi videobuf2_common snd_hwdep snd_seq_device fat btbcm crct10dif_pclmul btintel crc32_pclmul drm_kms_helper ghash_clmulni_intel cfg80211 bluetooth snd_pcm videodev mousedev ipmi_devintf snd_timer igb joydev aesni_intel ccp i2c_algo_bit input_leds ecdh_generic crypto_simd ipmi_msghandler snd mc cryptd glue_helper syscopyarea sp5100_tco sysfillrect usblp sysimgblt pcspkr i2c_piix4 k10temp soundcore ecc     rfkill fb_sys_fops rng_core dca
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel:  wmi pinctrl_amd gpio_amdpt evdev mac_hid acpi_cpufreq nf_log_ipv6 ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 xt_hl ip6t_rt nf_log_ipv4 nf_log_common ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_LOG xt_multiport xt_comment xt_limit xt_addrtype xt_tcpudp xt_conntrack ip6table_filter ip6_tables nf_conntrack_netbios_ns nf_conntrack_broadcast nf_nat_ftp nf_nat nf_conntrack_ftp nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 iptable_filter vmmon(OE) drm vmw_vmci sg crypto_user agpgart ip_tables x_tables     ext4 crc16 mbcache jbd2 dm_cache_smq dm_cache dm_persistent_data libcrc32c crc32c_generic dm_bio_prison dm_bufio dm_mod sr_mod cdrom sd_mod hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid uas hid usb_storage ahci libahci libata crc32c_intel xhci_pci scsi_mod xhci_hcd
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: CR2: 0000000000006f80
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: ---[ end trace a49b07b595862a96 ]---
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: RIP: 0010:_nv002476kms+0x60/0x100 [nvidia_modeset]
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: Code: eb 40 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 48 c7 03 00 00 00 00 c6 43 08 00 41 8b 86 d8 00 00 00 83 c5 01 48 81 c3 d0 03 00 00 39 e8 76 18 <48> 8b 3b 48 85 ff 74 ea 80 7b 08 00 75 d2 e8 ed d2 ff ff eb cb 0f
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: RSP: 0018:ffff9a2980e6bba8 EFLAGS: 00010202
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: RAX: 0000000000000004 RBX: 0000000000006f80 RCX: 0000000000000004
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: RDX: 0000000000000060 RSI: 0000000000006f80 RDI: ffff8e335e887008
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: RBP: 0000000000000000 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: R10: 0000000000000004 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: 0000000000006f80
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: R13: 0000000000006f80 R14: ffff8e335e887008 R15: 0000000000000001
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: FS:  00007fe00882edc0(0000) GS:ffff8e338e9c0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kernel: CR2: 0000000000006f80 CR3: 00000003f0b3c000 CR4: 00000000003406e0
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kded5[2039]: The X11 connection broke: I/O error (code 1)
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC systemd-journald[485]: Suppressed 46540 messages from session-2.scope
```

And then a bunch of:

```
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC baloorunner[5602]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC at-spi-bus-launcher[2384]: X connection to :0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC mono[2493]: Duplicati.GUI.TrayIcon: Fatal IO error 104 (Connection reset by peer) on X server :0.
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC yakuake[2266]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kleopatra[2229]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kmix[2253]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kdeconnectd[2183]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC akregator[2216]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC DiscoverNotifier[2181]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC akonadi_birthdays_resource[4110]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC gmenudbusmenuproxy[2178]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC akonadi_unifiedmailbox_agent[4126]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC kgpg[2203]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC xembedsniproxy[2155]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC akonadi_mailfilter_agent[4121]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC akonadi_maildir_resource[4119]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC akonadi_indexing_agent[4114]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC akonadi_contacts_resource[4111]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC akonadi_migration_agent[4122]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC akonadi_akonotes_resource[4108]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC akonadi_followupreminder_agent[4112]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC com.teamviewer.TeamViewer[2058]: X connection to :0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC com.teamviewer.TeamViewer[2058]: double free or corruption (!prev)
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC akonadi_newmailnotifier_agent[4123]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC org_kde_powerdevil[2320]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC korgac[2194]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC pulseaudio[2186]: X connection to :0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC akonadi_notes_agent[4124]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Mar 13 20:03:48 Ethan-PC polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[2151]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
```

So basically my question is, what is going on here? The only thing I know of is that "page allocation failures" are typically problems with RAM; I'm considering swapping mine out anyway because I don't think I have enough (but at the time, I wasn't doing anything RAM-intensive).

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

It's Nvidia driver. Unfortunately there is not much you can do about it at the moment. Nvidia needs to fix it and from what I read, it's going on for a while.